# SyntaxError: invalid syntax doing pset9 finance

Tags: python, html

I've tried everything, i'm doing FINANCE pset9 syntax error

```
File "/home/ubuntu/finance/application.py", line 259 else: ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

here is my application.py code:

```
@app.route("/sell", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def sell():
        """Sell shares of stock"""
        if request.method == "POST":
            find_missing_errors = is_provided("symbol") or is_provided("shares")
        if find_missing_errors:
            return find_missing_errors
        elif not request.form.get("shares").isdigit():
            return apology("invalid number of shares")
        symbol = request.form.get("symbol").upper()
        shares = int(request.form.get("shares"))
        stock = lookup(symbol)
        if stock is None:
            return apology("invalid symbol")
            
        db.execute("""
            SELECT SUM(shares) as totalShares
            FROM transactions
            WHERE
            
        """)
        
        rows = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id= :id", id=session["user_id"])
        cash = rows [0]["cash"]
        
        updated_cash = cash + shares * stock['price']
        if updated_cash < 0:
            return apology("can't afford")
        db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash=:updated_cash WHERE id= :id",
                    updated_cash=updated_cash,
                    id=session["user_id"])
        db.execute("""
            INSERT INTO transactions 
                (user_id, symbol, shares, price)
            VALUES (:user_id, :symbol, :shares, :price)
            """,
            user_id=session["user_id"],
            symbol = stock["symbol"],
            shares = shares,
            price = stock["price"]
        )    
        flash("Bought!")    
        return redirect("/")    
else: #<<=== line 259
    (rows = db.execute("""
    SELECT symbol
    FROM transactions
    WHERE user_id=:user_id
    GROUP BY symbol
    HAVING SUM(shares) > 0;
    """, user_id=session["user_id"]))
    return render_template("sell.html", symbols=[ row["symbol"] for row in rows ])

    
def errorhandler(e):
    """Handle error"""
    if not isinstance(e, HTTPException):
        e = InternalServerError()
    return apology(e.name, e.code)


# Listen for errors
for code in default_exceptions:
    app.errorhandler(code)(errorhandler)
```

Comment: ive tried indexining else and the code below they put: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: What `if` is the the `else` supposed to match with?

Comment: The line `(rows = db.execute...` doesn't make sense. Why are you wrapping the whole assignment in parentheses? That's invalid syntax. Did you mean `rows = (db.execute...`? Also, there's an `else` above it but no corresponding `if` that's at the same indentation level that I can see, which is another syntax error. Although the indentation of your code seems like it got a little messed up when you posted this question. However that seems like your issue. It's not clear why you have an `else` there randomly.

Comment: yeah i deleted the ( before row im sorry

Comment: i have indexed them all( the else and the code below) they put IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: never mind guys i got it right